# Ninject IoC inheritance

Tags: c#

It is possible to do that?

```
interface ISerivce { .. } - Inside project Domain
class BaseService : IService { ... } - Inside project Web
class UserService : IService { ... } - Inside project infrastrucutre
```

And I want configure ninject to

IService -> BaseService but as inheritance not via constructor.

Comment: Does UserService inherit BaseService? On another note: you can only _implement_ interfaces not inherit them...

Comment: What do you mean by "I want configure ninject to IService -> BaseService" ?